# Table of Contents showing nothing other than the word "Contents"

Tags: table-of-contents

I use Latex in Jupyter Lab and for some reason when I try to add a table of contents to my document, I get nothing other than the word "Contents", as you can see in the image. I'm not using \section*, and I also found that I have the same issue with the list of Figures and List of Tables. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is the beginning of my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\title{\textbf{Experimental Investigations of Donor-Acceptor Pairs in Diamond} \\
\large A summary of work done from January 2020 to June 2021}
\author{Jeremy Estes}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\section{Introduction, Theoretical Model, Experimental Goals}

\subsection{Introduction}

This document provides a detailed summary

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your document example works fine. You only need to compile it at least twice.

Comment: If I recompile again before any editing the problem doesn't seem to change.

Answer (score 2):

As I already mentioned in my comment, your document example works fine and gives expected result. So here some basic explanation, what happens at compilation of any document with instruction `\tableofcontents`, `listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.

At the first compilation of your document example, LaTeX create file `<file name>.toc` where it write all section, subsection and subsubsection titles. Similarly it create files `<file name>.lof` for captions of figures and `<file name>.lot` for captions of tables.

At the second compilation instruction  `\tableofcontents` read this information from `.toc` and create table of contents  with title **Contents**, instruction `\listoffigures` read information information from `.lof` create **List of Figures** and `\listoftables` create on similar way **List of Tables**. Those tables/lists you should see in the folder, for example `.toc` looks like

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Introduction, Theoretical Model, Experimental Goals}{2}{section.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Introduction}{2}{subsection.1.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2}Theoretical Model}{2}{subsection.1.2}%
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Case 1}{2}{subsubsection.1.2.1}%
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Case 2}{2}{subsubsection.1.2.2}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.3}Experimental Goals}{2}{subsection.1.3}%
```

and it your case after two compilation appear on the first page of your document as:

[image]

On the second page you should see body of document, which looks as follows:

[image]

From both figures you can observe, that in my tests I add to your document example few more sub and subsubsections and one figure.

You should obtain the same result. If not, than happens something which is unknown to us. So, check, if you after first compilation are generated files `.toc`, `.lof` and `lot` and what is their contents. If they are empty, (what with your document example cannot happen) than you doing something strange.

In test I use the following extension of your document example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\title{\textbf{Experimental Investigations of Donor-Acceptor Pairs in Diamond} \\
\large A summary of work done from January 2020 to June 2021}
\author{Jeremy Estes}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\clearpage

\section{Introduction, Theoretical Model, Experimental Goals}

\subsection{Introduction}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\caption{Owner of diamants}
\label{fig:duck}
    \end{figure}
    
\subsection{Theoretical Model}
    \subsubsection{Case 1}
    \subsubsection{Case 2}
\subsection{Experimental Goals}

This document provides a detailed summary

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah I see, this is really helpful, thank you! I do in fact see the .toc and other files like you mention. When I open one of them up it looks like they have the expected content. However, the issue seems to be that they disappear from the directory before I'm able to recompile a second time. I compile once and the .toc file appears for a few seconds, and before I'm able to compile a second time it disappears. I wonder if this is an issue with the way my mac is dealing with the temporary files?

Comment: @JeremyEstes. I haven Mac, so i haven't any experience with it. I use MikTeX on Windows 10 machine, So I'm surprised, that Mac work differently as other machines. This is strange. You may have strange settings of used editor, however in this I cant help you.